# URL Rewrite : Pointing wildcard url to its subfolder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to show content of wildcard url to its particular subfolder ..

For Example

Right now `http://youbridge.info/watchvideosonline/random-hello.html` is showing content of home page , instead i need to show contents of that particular `subfolder/index.php` (i.e content of `http://youbridge.info/watchvideosonline/`)

I tried below code , but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?filter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want to rewrite what url to what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*$ /$1/index.php [L]
```